# First non-repeating character in a stream

Tags: java, string, algorithm, data-structures

My answer to this question is as follows, but I want to know if I can use this code and what will be the complexity:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class FirstNonRepeatingCharacterinAString {

    private char firstNonRepeatingCharacter(String str) {       
        LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer> hash =
                new LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer>();

        for(int i = 0 ; i< str.length() ; i++)
        {
            if(hash.get(str.charAt(i))==null)
                hash.put(str.charAt(i), 1);
            else
                hash.put(str.charAt(i), hash.get(str.charAt(i))+1);
        }

        System.out.println(hash.toString());

        for(Entry<Character, Integer> c : hash.entrySet())
        {
            if(c.getValue() == 1)
                return c.getKey();
        }

        return 0 ;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String str = "geeksforgeeks";
        FirstNonRepeatingCharacterinAString obj =
                new FirstNonRepeatingCharacterinAString();
        char c = obj.firstNonRepeatingCharacter(str);
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: *I want to know if I can use this code.* Is this a copyright question?

Comment: Complexity of this code is O(n). But your code seems not returning what mentioned in title.

Comment: I just wanted to know, if this solution works.. it is not a copyright question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question about whether you "can use this code" is a little ambiguous - if you wrote it, I'd think you can use it :)

As for the complexity, it is `O(n)` where `n` is the number of characters in the `String`.  To count the number of occurrences, you must iterate over the entire `String`, plus iterate over them again to find the first one with a count of `1`. In the worst case, you have no non-repeating characters, or the only non-repeating character is the last one.  In either case, you have to iterate over the whole `String` once more.  So it's `O(n+n) = O(n)`.

**EDIT**

There is a bug in your code, by the way. Because you are using an *insertion-order* `LinkedHashMap`, each call to `put(Character,Integer)` results in a re-ordering of the underlying list.  You should probably use a `LinkedHashMap<Character,int[]>` instead, and check for the presence of keys before putting.  If they exist, then merely increment the value stored in the `int[]` to avoid re-ording the map by making another `put` call. Even so, the resulting list will be in reverse order from the way you iterate over it, so the *first* non-repeating character will be the last one you find when iterating over it whose value is 1. Alternatively, you could just iterate in reverse in your first `for` loop, then you avoid having to always go through the entire `Entry` set if the first non-repeating character comes sooner than the final character in the original `String`.